# Unable to create enviornmental setting for batch process

Tags: azure, mpi, azure-batch

I am trying to execute a mpi-based task with python-sdk for batch pool.

My setup includes the following steps:

- Create the pool from template json.
- Create SAS URLs and upload the executable & supporting files as common resource files.
- Create the Task Object

  - Add Environmental settings to tasks. (using azure.batch.models.EnvironmentSetting)
  - Add the coordination script and run_script.

The coordination script looks like:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

export MPI_HOME="/usr/local/openmpi4.0/openmpi-4.0.0/build"
export CUDA_HOME="/usr/local/cuda-11.0"

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MPI_HOME/lib:$CUDA_HOME/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export PATH="$MPI_HOME/bin:$CUDA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
```

The run_script looks like:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

export MPI_HOME="/usr/local/openmpi4.0/openmpi-4.0.0/build"
export CUDA_HOME="/usr/local/cuda-11.0"

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MPI_HOME/lib:$CUDA_HOME/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export PATH="$MPI_HOME/bin:$CUDA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"

mpirun -np 3 --prefix /usr/local/openmpi4.0/openmpi-4.0.0/build --map-by ppr:4:node --oversubscribe --mca btl_openib_allow_ib 1 -host $AZ_BATCH_HOST_LIST $AZ_BATCH_TASK_SHARED_DIR/EXECUTABLE_FILE $AZ_BATCH_TASK_SHARED_DIR/INPUT_FILE_WITH_PARAMS
```

I am stuck with the error:

```
/path/to/my/executable: error while loading shared libraries: libmpi.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Clearly, the env settings is not working.

Can you point to how can I go about the env setup for the tasks ?

Comment: it looks like your application was built with MPICH (`libmpi.so.12`) and you are trying to run it with Open MPI 4.0.0. You cannot mix MPI implementations, so either set your environment to use MPICH or rebuild your app with Open MPI

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Does OpenMPI have a different name for the mpi library? Or how did you draw that conclusion?

Comment: Open MPI 4.0 has`libmpi.so.40`. a quick google search of `libmpi.so.12` points to MPICH.